# Specifying template in AngularJS route gives unexpected request URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In AngularJS, I have my routes setup like this:

```
discountLinkApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
  function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/discount-links', {
        templateUrl: 'js/partials/discount-links.html',
        controller: 'discountLinkController'
      }).
      when('/register/:tag', {
        templateUrl: 'js/partials/register.html',
        controller: 'paymentPageController'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/discount-links'
      });

    //Removes the # from the URL
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

My root directory structure is setup like this:

```
├── index.php
├── js
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── mainCtrl.js
│   ├── partials
│   │   ├── discount-links.html
│   │   └── register.html
│   └── services
│       └── discountLinkService.js
└── views
    └── index.php
```

For the `/discount-links` route, AngularJS generates the correct request:

```
/js/partials/discount-links.html
```

However, the '/register/:tag` route decides to look for

```
/register/js/partials/register.html
```

***Note the extra `/register/`* segment which does not exist so I get a 404.**

I am struggling to work out why this is happening. The only difference is the `:tag` between the two routes.

I can prepend `../` to the templateUrl to make it `../js/partials/register.html`, but this is not consistent to me.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. Just use absolute path in a templateUrl property. This means you'll have to change this:

```
js/partials/discount-links.html
```

to this:

```
/js/partials/discount-links.html
```

And it'll work on every path.